# Is aquamarine considered to be a compound word?

Tags: compounds

We've been debating whether or not aquamarine is a compound word or not. To me, I view "aqua" as being just a prefix rather than a standalone word, so I don't think aquamarine would be considered to be a compound word.

Comment: it would be a prefix if it were a prefix, not a suffix.

Comment: Ah yes, I definitely meant prefix. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

It comes from the Latin phrase 'aqua marina' meaning 'water of the sea'.  So it would be a compound word, either in Latin or when coined, rather than a prefix.

For it to be a prefix, it would have to be a type of **marina**, modified to be related to water. It is a gemstone.  And all marinas are water related.

Comment: I can see it being a compound word in Latin, but would it still be considered to be a compound in English?

Comment: If the Romans did the compounding, then I would say no. But not because aqua- is a prefix, but because the word was imported in one package.

Comment: And if the Romano-Brits did the compounding? 'Aquamarine' seems to be in the grey area. I liked it better the way it was.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is a compound word and it is from this compound dictionary: **Compounding in the English language**; . Ball, Alice Morton.

List of compound words that begin with aqua:

-green

**marine**

meter

plane

tint

tone

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say here. Could you please add some explanation?